# Replacing every third comma

Tags: javascript, regex

This works to replace every other comma.  What do I have to do to replace every third comma?

```
resultContent = resultContent.replace(/(,[^,]*),/g, '$1|');
```

Comment: Assuming you have no line breaks I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

```
resultContent = resultContent.replace(/((?:,[^,]*){2}),/g, '$1|');
```